# Wordpress Redirection with Regex and keep querysting data

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to have new redirect rules using regex, and need to reuse some of the data in the new URL format. 
Old URL structure:
http://www.example.com/shop/checkout/order-received/DATA1?key=DATA2

NEW URL Structure:
http://www.example.com/?page_id=12874&order-received=DATA1&key=DATA2

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's your example, but what you're trying to achieve is wrong in terms of [clean URL's in SEO](https://moz.com/blog/seo-cheat-sheet-anatomy-of-a-url).

Comment: I know, all URL's except this one and another one works with clean URL. Thanks for the advice.